# From static block we can't access super() or this() but in static Initialization block how can we access a constructor?

Tags: java

Please see the below singleton class Test created in which static block and static method are accessing same Test class constructor. When this() super() calls are not allowed in static block or static method and how constructor is being accessed from static area. Could you please explain in detail. Thank you!

```
class Test{

    static Test t;

    //********
    static{
        t = new Test();
    }
    //*****


    static Test getRef(){

        if(t==null)
        {
          t= new Test();
              return t;     
            
        }
        
        else
        {
          
          return t;
                    
        }

        

    }

    private Test()
    {

    }


}
class Driver{


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Test t1 = Test.getRef();
        Test t2 = Test.getRef();    
        
        System.out.println(t1);
        System.out.println(t2);
    }


}
```

Comment: "how constructor is being accessed from static area" Because `new Test()` is neither `this()` nor `super()`? Did you think `new Test()` is the same as `this()`?

Answer (score 0):

`this()` and `super()` are calls from a derived-class constructor to a superclass contstructor. They are therefore only value when constructing an object, i.e., an instance of a class.

static methods and members are by definition not a part of any specific instance.  There is no instance for `this()` to refer to and nor is there any superclass instance for `super()` to refer to.

`new Something()` creates, that is it constructs, a new instance of the `Something class`.  It is an implicit call to the constructor of `Something`. That constructor execution can of course use the facilities provided for constructors: `this()` and `super()` included.

I suspect the fundamental issue here is lack of clarity about the distinction between class and object (instance).

Answer (score 0):

As you know the rules of static e.i Only static fields and members are accessed inside static block.

**1. Note** - The constructors are always non-static. Therefore we can't access static fields or member inside constructors.

**2. Note** -Static block are executed before the object creation (executing constructor). That's why using this feature in creation of singleton class. Making constructor private and create object inside static block.

**Example of singleton class**

```
public class Foo {
    static Foo singletonObj;

    static {
        singletonObj = new Foo();
    }
    private Foo() { }
}
```